# ORA delete / truncate

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate, sql-loader

I'm using SQL loader to load my data into database.

Before I insert the data I need to remove existing data in the table:

```
options(skip=1,load=250000,errors=0,ROWS=30000,BINDSIZE=10485760)
load data
infile 'G:1.csv' "str '^_^'"
replace
into table IMPORT_ABC
fields terminated by "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
trailing nullcols(
.
.
.
.)
```

But I got error like:

SQL*LOADER-926: OCI error while executing delete/truncate  for table IMPORT_ABC
ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'undo1'

How can I delete data for example by 10000 rows?
I know that I have some limit on my DB.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be recoverable - presumably not if you're replacing anyway - is there a reason you're using [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#sthref660) rather than [`truncate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#sthref669)?

Comment: no,
I just want to delete all the items from the table
and then instert a new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting records in batches can be done in a PL/SQL loop, but is generally considered bad practice as the entire delete should normally be considered as a single transaction; and that can't be done from within the SQL*Loader control file. Your DBA should size the `UNDO` space to accommodate the work you need to do.

If you're deleting the entire table you'll almost certainly be better off truncating anyway, either [in the control file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#sthref669):

```
options(skip=1,load=250000,errors=0,ROWS=30000,BINDSIZE=10485760)
load data
infile 'G:1.csv' "str '^_^'"
truncate
into table IMPORT_ABC
...
```

Or as a separate [`truncate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10007.htm) statement in SQL*Plus/SQL Developer/some other client before you start the load:

```
truncate table import_abc;
```

The disadvantage is that your table will appear empty to other users while the new rows are being loaded, but if it's a dedicated import area (guessing from the name) that may not matter anyway.

If your `UNDO` is really that small then you may have to run multiple loads, in which case - probably obviously - you need to make sure you only have the `truncate` in the control file for the first one (or use the separate `truncate` statement), and have [`append`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#sthref657) instead in subsequent control files as you noted in comments.

You might also want to consider [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) if you're using this data as a base to populate something else, as there is no `UNDO` overhead on replacing the external data source. You'll probably need to talk to your DBA about setting that up and giving you the necessary directory permissions.

Comment: can I do it like this:

fist sql*loader file:
    
`code options(skip=1,load=250000,errors=0,ROWS=30000,BINDSIZE=10485760)
    load data
    infile 'G:\Remediation metrics\Source data\Data Backup &     Recovery\ALL_admin_combined_report_v1.csv' "str '^_^'"
    truncate
    into table IMPORT_ABC.....

2nd sql*loader file:

options(skip=250001,load=250000,errors=0,ROWS=30000,BINDSIZE=10485760)
load data
infile '2.csv' "str '^_^'"
append
into table ..

3rd sql*loader:
    options(skip=500001,load=250000,errors=0,ROWS=30000,BINDSIZE=10485760)
load data
infile '1.csv' "str '^_^'"
append
into table

Comment: @user2207426 - yes, that's what I meant. Added a reference to the answer; thanks.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thx! It would work, but my user will not be granted truncate permissions. I have only delete privs. For now I use a separate sqlplus statement to delete the data and than sqlldr like above... But I'm not amused...

Answer (score 0):

Your undo tablespace is to small to hold all the undo information and it seems it cannot be extended.

You can split the import into smaller batched and issue a commit after each batch or get your DBA to increase the tablespace for undo1

And use truncate in stead of replace before you start the immports

Comment: The `replace` will attempt to delete everything in the table in the first run, however many records are being inserted; and subsequent runs with the same parameter would delete the rows you just inserted. Batching might be needed for the insert phase though...

Comment: yes,
I have data import split into 3 config files and it's ok

but I can't remove all the items (in DB) by once, somehow I need to delete them by 1000rows etc

how can I do it ?

Comment: Did you try truncate ? or you could try delete based on rowid http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689