# Oracle database - delete records from a fixed length file

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle Database and I am using `SQL*Loader` to load some fixed length files. That works fine.

The problem is I have to add support for deleting all record in a fixed length file. It looks I cannot use SQL*Loader for this and I have no ideea if /how this can be made in a PL/SQL file.

Anyone has an advice on this ?

Comment: `sqlldr` does not provide you the option to delete. It just loads. You can either load the data from the files into temporary tables then either use the `MERGE` statement or you can delete the data reading the temporary table data. However if you are considering to delete the entire table data. Consider truncating. as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878297/ora-delete-truncate)

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I dont want to delete entire table data. Just the dataset that is in the data file. A sort of rollback for SQL*Loader in the case we have errors. 

Using a temporary table or create a transaction will solve my problem. I just want to verify there is no faster/direct option.